# SQL Server equivalent for Oracle CURRVAL from dual

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012, cursor

What is the purpose of these Oracle block ? Especially the keyword `CURRVAL` and `ROWNUM` . How do I convert these statements into SQL Server 2012?

```
CURSOR cursor_1 IS
        SELECT ID.CURRVAL identity FROM dual;

CURSOR cursor_2 IS
        SELECT COUNT(*) Count_total  FROM tbl1
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: OPEN c3;
FETCH c3 INTO c3_rec;
IF c3%NOTFOUND OR c3_rec.id IS NULL THEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURRVAL gets the current value (without increasing it) of an Oracle sequence. (NEXTVAL increases the sequence and retrieves the new current value.) See documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253

Your cursor_1 is simply retrieving the current value of a sequence named "ID".

SQL Server I believe does not have sequences, but I am not sure if Microsoft might have added something like it in newer releases? SQL Server uses identity columns and not sequences. The cursor cannot be converted to SQL Server in a meaningful fashion. You would have to know what is the purpose of the cursor? Probably it would have to be replaced by something like selecting the value of the identity column of the newly inserted row (if this is happening just after inserting into a table with a trigger that uses ID.NEXTVAL for example.)

--

WHERE ROWNUM = 1 just selects one "random" row from tbl1 and counts it. So count_total will be either 0 or 1 depending on whether rows exist in tbl1 or not. Perhaps that can be replaced with a SELECT TOP 1, but I am not sure if a COUNT in a TOP query counts *after* the TOP has been processed or *before* the TOP.

Comment: might sound terribly silly but when I ask for the `current value` of a sequence from an inserted trigger would it look for the last value in the table before the `inserted table` values ? So say before the insert command the last value was 10 but now I have 2 rows in the inserted table. What value would `CURRVAL`  get  at that point .

Comment: Say you have created a sequence like "CREATE SEQUENCE MYSEQ;" When you use "MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL", you get the value and the sequence is incremented. Then when you use "MYSEQ.CURRVAL" you will get the same value as the last time your session executed "MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL", no matter if you used NEXTVAL in a trigger or as part of the insert statement or in a procedure. If a table column is populated in a trigger using nextval, the best way to retrieve that value is using RETURNING clause in the INSERT statement - it will be safer than CURRVAL as CURRVAL is just "the last time NEXTVAL was called."

Comment: Sorry I think I am mixing IDENTITY column with SEQUENCE

Comment: IDENTITY column in Oracle version 12c (older Oracle versions do not have IDENTITY) is implemented behind the scenes as sequences anyway, you just do not have access to NEXTVAL/CURRVAL yourself. For those you need to use RETURNING clause of INSERT to get what identity value the row actually got. I assume (but don't know) that SQL Server may have same RETURNING mechanism (but it may have different syntax.)

Comment: HI Kim , could you please give an example of the RETURNING clause in the INSERT statement ?

Comment: If you have a variable the_inserted_id and a table that populates column my_pk via a sequence in a trigger or identity column, you can do something like "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('abc', 123) RETURNING my_pk INTO the_inserted_id". At least that'll be the syntax if the insert is done in a PL/SQL stored procedure (which is where I like to do inserts ;-)) I think (not quite sure) that if you are inserting from other environment, you might use ":the_inserted_id" and bind an output variable to your statement.